# "unexpected token :" while loading json

Tags: javascript, json, requirejs

I'm trying to load a local JSON file in a html page to then search for a match and take the related informations, but I'm having some troubles with the loading part.

Right now, when a click on an area, the header changes, while the body remains the same, and I get 2 errors in the console: "unexpected token :" and "json is undefined", the first regarding the ":" after "list" in the second row of my JSON, while the other regards the json used in the $(#IOC)... line of my JS code.

olympics.json:

```
{
"list": [
{
"Country": "United States",
"IOC": "USA",
"Summer_Gold": "1,070",
"Summer_Silver": 841,
"Summer_Bronze": 745,
"Summer_Total": "2,656",
"Winter_Gold": 105,
"Winter_Silver": 113,
"Winter_Bronze": 89,
"Winter_Total": 307,
"Total_Gold": "1,175",
"Total_Silver": 954,
"Total_Bronze": 834,
"Total_Total": "2,963"
},
...
]}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<area class="ModArea" target="" alt="Iceland" title="Iceland" coords="138,388,35,540,232,748,549,585,516,374"
      shape="poly" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">   
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="country_name"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="IOC">IOC: </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    $(".ModArea").click(function () {
        var name = $(this).attr('title');
        $("#country_name").html(name);
        require(['/static/olympics.json'], function (json) {
            $("#IOC").html(json.list.find(element => element.Country === name));
        });
    });
```

Comment: The provided JSON does not give that error. Please check that `/static/olympics.json` is valid JSON?

Comment: Try `$.getJSON('/static/olympics.json', function (json) {` instead.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the JSON I put is exactly the same one as the one in `/static/olympics.json`, the only difference is that this one has only 1 item instead of 200

@ChrisG I gives me "$.getJSON is not a function"

Comment: Could you try opening the json file in the browser itself, something like http://localhost:5000/static/olympics.json & check if it works. It might reveal authentication errors.

Comment: @NiceBooks yeah if I open it in the browser it gives me 0 errors and works exactly as intended: list is above all, then each country is given a number and inside that number there are all the informations

Comment: That's pretty weird, given [this](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/); did you change to jQuery *slim* by any chance?

Comment: @ChrisG I was already using jQuery slim, specifically https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem; you need the regular one. The slim version doesn't have the ajax functions. The code in your question links to the regular one, so it should've worked just fine.

Comment: it works now! the only problem left is that the IOC is being returned with the quotation marks but I'll try to find an answer in the morning lol

Comment: I do believe that you have to use the RequireJS JSON plugin: https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins

Answer (score 0):

You name of course needs to match the thing you want

this works better. You need to only get the JSON once

```js
let element;
require(['/static/olympics.json'], function(json) {
  element = json;
  $(".ModArea").on("click", function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('title');
    $("#country_name").html(name);
    const countryData = element.list.find(element => element.Country === name);
    $("#IOC").html(JSON.stringify(countryData))
  });
});
```

Test code

```js
const json = {
  "list": [{
    "Country": "Iceland",
    "IOC": "IS",
    "Summer_Gold": "1,070",
    "Summer_Silver": 841,
    "Summer_Bronze": 745,
    "Summer_Total": "2,656",
    "Winter_Gold": 105,
    "Winter_Silver": 113,
    "Winter_Bronze": 89,
    "Winter_Total": 307,
    "Total_Gold": "1,175",
    "Total_Silver": 954,
    "Total_Bronze": 834,
    "Total_Total": "2,963"
  }, ]
}


$(".ModArea").click(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr('title');
  $("#country_name").html(name);
  const countryData =json.list.find(element => element.Country === name); 
  $("#IOC").html(JSON.stringify(countryData))
  console.log(name,$("#IOC").html())
  /*
  
  require(['/static/olympics.json'], function(json) {
    $("#IOC").html(json.list.find(element => element.Country === name));
  });
  
  */



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="europe_img" src="https://mapswire.com/download/europe/europe-political-map-miller.jpg" usemap="#europe" alt="Europe">
<map name="europe">

    <area class="ModArea" target="" alt="Iceland" title="Iceland" coords="138,388,35,540,232,748,549,585,516,374"
          shape="poly" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">   
    <div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="country_name"></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p id="IOC">IOC: </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</map>
```

Comment: the problem with this is that my current json has over 200 countries, so I don't think that pasting it all in a html would be possible

Comment: You still use the Jason but I could not use Ajax in my answer

Comment: what I mean is that in your answer you didn't use a JSON file, but instead put what was inside the file in a const, something I can't do because my JSON file is formed by over 200 of those object, which would make the variable over a 1000 lines long

Comment: See new update. You should only get the file once

Comment: the errors remain the same as before, the only difference is that now the "unexpected token :" error is shown as soon as the page is reloaded (this makes me doubt that the JSON is written correctly, but https://jsonlint.com/ says that it's a completely fine JSON)

Comment: Then I cannot help. Your script works with the snippet of object you posted

Comment: really weird mystery we got here, but thanks for helping!